# Getting location address instead of value while printing using pointers with structures?

Tags: c

I have this structure and using pointers , I am trying to print the values of different structure variables , but for int variables it prints location address instead of value and for char variables the result is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct calc{

    int row;
    int col;
    int menu_name[20];
    int sub_menu_name[20]; 

    };




int main()
{
int count = 0, i = 0;

struct calc *P_calc[2];

//p_calc = (struct calc *)malloc(sizeof(struct calc)*2);


for(count; count<1; count++)
{
      P_calc[count] = (struct calc *)malloc(sizeof(struct calc));

       printf("Please enter the row cordinates: \n");

       scanf("%d",P_calc[i]->row);
       printf("Please enter the col cordinates: \n");

       scanf("%d",P_calc[i]->col);
       printf("Please enter the menu_name: \n");

       scanf("%s",P_calc[i]->menu_name);
       printf("Please enter the sub_menu_name: \n");

       scanf("%s",P_calc[i]->sub_menu_name);


}

   for(i; i<1; i++)  
       {        
        printf("row : %d\n",P_calc[i]->row);

        printf("col :%d\n",P_calc[i]->col);

        printf("menu_name: %s\n",P_calc[i]->menu_name);

        printf("sub_menu_name :%s\n",P_calc[i]->sub_menu_name);
        }


system("PAUSE");
return 0;    
}
```

Please Help Me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please make a habit of adding actual and desired output and/or comments indicating which lines print what and what they should print.

Comment: Sorry buddy ...i will follow that next time when i post...thanks for your advice

Answer (score 3):

Here are your problems:

1. The structure should be

   ```
   struct calc{

   int row;
   int col;
   char menu_name[20];
   char sub_menu_name[20]; 

   };
   ```
2. `scanf("%d",P_calc[i]->row);`should be `scanf("%d",&P_calc[i]->row);`
3. `scanf("%d",P_calc[i]->col);`should be `scanf("%d",&P_calc[i]->col);`

It is also a good idea to check the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks friend...i am such a stupid that i forgot the basics ...thanks a lot!

Comment: @studyembedded , everyone makes mistakes , thats how learning happens !!

Answer (score 0):

The scanf statement should be

```
scanf("%d",&P_calc[i]->row);
```

The address needs to be passed to scanf. Similarly while reading the col variable.